# ipv6 forwarding kills ipv6 connection?

Tags: networking, server, 14.04, ipv6, docker

Hi i'm trying to spin up VMs on public ipv6 address's.

When I enable `net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1` on the host it seems to kill the ipv6 connectivity

```
root@li166-218:~# ip -6 route show dev eth0
2600:3c01::/64  proto kernel  metric 256  expires 2591994sec
fe80::/64  proto kernel  metric 256
default via fe80::1  proto ra  metric 1024  expires 84sec
root@li166-218:~# traceroute -6 google.com
traceroute to google.com (2607:f8b0:4010:801::1000), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
 1  2600:3c01::8678:acff:fe0d:79c1 (2600:3c01::8678:acff:fe0d:79c1)  0.860 ms  0.915 ms  1.005 ms
 2  10gigabitethernet8-2.core3.fmt2.he.net (2001:470:1:3b8::1)  10.615 ms  10.608 ms  7.144 ms
 3  10ge5-4.core1.pao1.he.net (2001:470:0:263::2)  6.539 ms  6.601 ms  6.653 ms
 4  google-as15169.10gigabitethernet8-2.core1.pao1.he.net (2001:470:0:244::2)  0.937 ms  0.905 ms  0.882 ms
 5  2001:4860::1:0:21 (2001:4860::1:0:21)  9.843 ms  9.812 ms  9.740 ms
 6  2001:4860:0:1::3d5 (2001:4860:0:1::3d5)  1.974 ms  1.712 ms  1.979 ms
 7  2607:f8b0:8000:24::2 (2607:f8b0:8000:24::2)  1.575 ms 2607:f8b0:8000:24::7 (2607:f8b0:8000:24::7)  1.637 ms 2607:f8b0:8000:24::1 (2607:f8b0:8000:24::1)  1.684 ms
root@li166-218:~# sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
root@li166-218:~# traceroute -6 google.com
traceroute to google.com (2607:f8b0:4010:801::1000), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
connect: Network is unreachable
```

when `net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1` I can ping the host from the guest vm. Hoever the host no longer has public ipv6 connectivity.

Comment: How is your virtual network set up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enabling IPv6 forwarding will disable IPv6 autoconf. Usually you want routers (devices that forward) to have static addresses.

This is documented in the [Linux IPv6 HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/proc-sys-net-ipv6..html).

Here is the relevant part:

> **forwarding**
>
> Type: BOOLEAN
>
> Default: FALSE if global forwarding is disabled (default), otherwise
>   TRUE
>
> Configure interface-specific Host/Router behaviour.
>
> Note: It is recommended to have the same setting on all interfaces;
>   mixed router/host scenarios are rather uncommon.
>
> Value FALSE: By default, Host behaviour is assumed. This means:
>
> - IsRouter flag is not set in Neighbour Advertisements.
> - Router Solicitations are being sent when necessary.
> - If accept_ra is TRUE (default), accept Router Advertisements (and do autoconfiguration).
> - If accept_redirects is TRUE (default), accept Redirects.
>
> Value TRUE: If local forwarding is enabled, Router behaviour is
>   assumed. This means exactly the reverse from the above:
>
> - IsRouter flag is set in Neighbour Advertisements.
> - Router Solicitations are not sent.
> - Router Advertisements are ignored.
> - Redirects are ignored.

By setting forwarding to TRUE your machine will behave like a router. You either need to force it to accept Router Advertisements (RAs) or you need to manually configure your addresses and routes.

To enable autoconf even when using forwarding use this:

> **accept_ra**
>
> Type: BOOLEAN
>
> Accept Router Advertisements; autoconfigure using them.
>
> Possible values are:
>
> - 0: Do not accept Router Advertisements.
> - 1: Accept Router Advertisements if forwarding is disabled.
> - 2: Overrule forwarding behaviour. Accept Router Advertisements even if forwarding is enabled.

Yes, it's a boolean with values 0, 1 and 2 :)

Comment: Setting accept_ra=2 fixed it :\

Answer (score 1):

Enabling forwarding will wipe out the default route. You can add it back with:

```
ip -6 route add default via <ipv6 gateway address> dev <interface>
```

As soon as it is added, IPv6 connectivity should be fine again.

In my case, I had to find the gateway address by snooping around in my cable modem via `http://192.168.100.1`.